# VBS printer script executing error

Tags: printing, vbscript, printers, wsh

I have some trouble executing/using vbs scripts linked to printers. They are located in %windir%/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts

The objective is to plan a weekly print task to preserve ink cartridge

Looking at the scripts, everything was available for me to create this task
The main script to use is [prnqctl.vbs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730914.aspx)

Before to create my task, I have tried to test the script and this is what I got (sorry for the french version, I will try to update the screenshot in english later):

[image]

There is obviously something wrong.
I have tried to google the error code, nothing conclusive.
I have tried to run my script in admin mode and also under admin session, same problem
I have made some research on CIMWin32, it seems to be a dll and I can find it in some locations of my filesystem

My OS is W8.1.

If anybody has a suggestion or solution, I'm interested in

Answer (score 0):

```
==>cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnqctl.vbs -e
Unable to get printer instance. Error 0x80041002 Not found
Operation GetObject
Provider CIMWin32
Description
Win32 error code
```

The error culprit is clear: you should provide a valid `-p` argument. It's a mandatory parameter in case of `-e` operation:

```
==>cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnqctl.vbs -e -p "Fax"
Success Print Test Page Printer Fax

==>
```